# Rails 4 concurrent database indexes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, concurrency, rails-migrations, database-indexes

I am just wondering what is the correct behaviour when creating concurrent indexes in Rails.

I am using this in my migration file:

```
disable_ddl_transaction!

def change
    add_index :table_name, :field_name, algorithm: :concurrently
end
```

This should create a postgres concurrent index.

My question is: When running `rake db:migrate` Is the correct behaviour to wait for the creation of the index? I mean, the migration will wait until the index is created? Or it should end and delegate postgres that responsibility?

P.S. It is a really big index.

Comment: Are you using a special gem for this?

Comment: No. This is built-in in Rails 4 @beerlington. Nevertheless, I already tested access to the table I am creating the index for. I can write and read when the task is running (It takes 2 minutes aprox.). This tells me that the concurrency creation is working properly, but I just want to make sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found out it is the correct behavior.
Regardless the migration is waiting, the index will be created concurrently as expected.

Writes and reads are allowed in creation time.

Comment: This did not work for me as expected.  Indexing 10 millions rows locked the database on Rails 4.0.8.

Comment: @Ponny for Rails 4.0.8 they made some changes in ActiveRecord, but regarding some datatypes. This should still work for that version. I just did it recently on 4.0.5

Comment: Found the issue.  Was adding columns and multiple indexes.  Some reading suggested that I put the concurrent index in its own migration.  Worked fine then on 30 mil rows on SSD.  Took 20 mins and had no issues/locks.

Comment: @Ponny brilliant! And yes, It's a good practice to place indexes in their own migrations. Even more if they are concurrent indexes.